# Can excell put fields in a template that can then be copied as regular text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2010, text-formatting, data-transfer

Ive been trying to figure this out but havent found many answers for this function.  Essentially what I am trying to do is have Excell put my data fields in a text template so I can copy and paste them into another program.

[image: Example]

What I would like to do is have fields drop in to this text template:

**"F180"**
Rim:**"D180"**
(N):**"I180" "J180"** IE:**"H180"**
BTM:**"P180"**

*(The items that are not bold would just be text that I enter and then excell populates the Bold items in the correct spot in the statement.)*

(The "P180" isnt the correct field, but you get the idea) (There also appears to be some formatting issues in this fourm submisson acoording to the preview, but I think my point is getting across.)

So the text file would read as a final example:

*MH
Rim:44.447
(N):8 CONC IE:44.447
BTM:44.447*

I would then like to be able to copy and paste this as text only into another program.

Any ideas Super Users?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a simpler example, I really don't get what you're trying to do here. Also, how is Word involved? It's not mentioned anywhere in the question directly, so if it's not involved, the tag shouldn't be on the question. If it is involved somehow, please make clearer how.

Comment: I was looking to get plain text generated into a document that was sourced form a Excell Workbook.  I wanted the text to be generated from certain cells that would change depending on input, however certain words in the the data would not be sourced from the excell file, such as this simplified example:  Apples: 5  Oranges:  3.  (where apples and oranges would be template text and the numbers 5 & 3 would be pulled from the spreadsheet to generate a text statement that says "Apples 5" or "Oranges: 3"

Comment: That way I can copy the text I need into a different program without typing all of the text that would otherwise be required.  Word could be useful in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can just use one of the following formulas in its own cell on a new sheet.

```
=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!F180, " Rim:", Sheet1!D180, " (N):", Sheet1!I180, " ", Sheet1!J180, " IE:", Sheet1!H180, " BTM:", Sheet1!P180)
```

OR

```
=Sheet1!F180 & " Rim:" & Sheet1!D180 & " (N):" & Sheet1!I180 & " " & Sheet1!J180 & " IE:" & Sheet1!H180 & " BTM:" & Sheet1!P180
```

Just replace "Sheet1" with what ever sheet your table is on then you can just select the cell that you entered this formula into and click `Ctrl-C` or just right click on the cell and click copy.

This gives me the following when I copy it...

> ColF Rim:ColD (N):ColI ColJ IE:ColH BTM:ColP

Comment: Haha, no problem, glad to help! Plus now I have comment permission which is great so thank you!